# window.print in chrome forced separate page not working

Tags: php, google-chrome, printing, fpdf

Hi i searched a lot but i can't find any answer.I just want forced separate print in chrome.I have two tables in my print page.i want them to print in seperate pages.So far I tried this

```
<?php
$htmlTable='<TABLE>
<TR>
    <TD>Name:</TD>
    <TD>Sanooj</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Email:</TD>
    <TD>SSJ$SANOOJ@gmail.com</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>URl:</TD>
    <TD>wwww.google.com</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Comment:</TD>
    <TD>hello</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>';
echo $htmlTable;
?>
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
<?php
echo $htmlTable;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.print();
setTimeout("window.close()", 50);
</script>
```

But when i use `page-break-after: always;` it shows two pages in print preview but print comes out as one.If there is a solution please answer.

Note:If you think using FPDF is better then i am ok, but problem is i need print directly from browser like when i click button it shows print preview page and print it.When I use FPDF it shows browser preview page then print preview page then prints.So i need to be fast like window.print method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'window.print' is a client side script for print. It's behavior is depends on the browser used .If you use it in chrome it behaves like chrome printing Or if yo use it in mozilla it behaves like mozilla printing. You can't customize those changes in general.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you miss the CSS

```
@media print
{
      .page-break  { display:block; page-break-before:always; }

}
```

This works for me..pls checkout